# WordPress REST API handle false value for empty ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the WordPress REST API to pull in data from a custom post type with custom fields.  I'm deserializing the info for each post to a class I created in my application.  This works great when all ACF fields are populated in the post, but I'm noticing that the API returns a value of "false" for empty fields rather than setting them to null or just excluding them from the JSON.  That causes problems when an unpopulated field returns a boolean value of false rather than the expected object, and I get an error like:

Error converting value False to type 'MvcApplication.Models.ResourceLibrary.searchResult+TaxonomyTerm'

Which makes sense, because this is my TaxonomyTerm class, and I'm expecting an object rather than a boolean value for the category field in the list of ACF fields:

```
        public class TaxonomyTerm
        {
            public int term_id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string slug { get; set; }
            public int term_group { get; set; }
            public int term_taxonomy_id { get; set; }
            public string taxonomy { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public int parent { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
            public string filter { get; set; }
        }
```

For example, here's what the ACF section of the JSON looks like for a post where most info is populated:

```
       "acf":{
         "author":"PR",
         "year":"2022",
         "keywords":"test keywords",
         "category":{
            "term_id":21,
            "name":"Audit Program",
            "slug":"audit-program",
            "term_group":0,
            "term_taxonomy_id":21,
            "taxonomy":"vl_cat",
            "description":"",
            "parent":0,
            "count":0,
            "filter":"raw"
         }
```

vs. one that has blank fields:

```
     "acf":{
         "author":"",
         "year":"",
         "keywords":"",
         "category":false,
         "bok_cats":false,
         "file":false,
         "external_url":"",
         "kentico_node_id":""
      }
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to handle the false values so that I can still deserialize to my class when the values are populated.

**UPDATE:** I noticed that this is only happening when I append ?acf_format=standard to the endpoint.  Without that, I get the empty/null behavior I would expect for unpopulated fields.  However, I need acf_format=standard in order to get the full object data for taxonomy terms, files, etc. and not just the IDs.